# For what $x$ and $y$, the sum of the factorials of $x$ and $y$ equals 10 factorial?

Tags: combinatorics

I read somewhere that, there exist two numbers $x$ and $y$ such that
 $x! + y! = 10!$.
But, the obvious calculations does not meet this criteria.
So, is this equation even solvable :
$x! + y! = 10!$

Comment: $x$ and $y$ must both be less than $10$; but then $x!+y!\le 9!+9!=2\cdot9!<10!$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surely the problem must be to find $x$ and $y$ such that the *product* of $x!$ and $y!$ is $10!$.

Notice that the last few factors of $10!$ are $\ldots 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10$, which factor into small primes. In particular, $8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10 = 720 = 6!$, so $10! = 7! \cdot 6!$.

Comment: (And if I am right in guessing that the problem is about products, then obviously we should require that $x,y > 1$.)

Comment: wow, really nice take :). I really should have thought that myself. A single character typo now make a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$$9!+9!=2\times 9!<10!<1+10!=0!+10!$$

Suppose $a\le b$.  If $b<10$ then $a!+b!< 10!$, and if $b\ge 10$ then $a!+b!>10!$.

What you read was in error.